# Upload and download xlsx files in django

Tags: django, amazon-s3, upload, celery, botocore

I'm trying to work with a view for file upload (xlsx) to s3. And a celery function that should download this file so that I can perform some actions.

My view:

```
class ImportView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser, )

    def post(self, request, filename):
        imported = ImportSerializer(data=request.data)
        fs = FileSystemStorage(tempfile.gettempdir())
        file_name = fs.save(content=new_colabs.validated_data["file"], name="import.xlsx")
        full_path = os.path.join(fs.location, file_name)
        object_name = file_name
        s3 = boto3.client("s3")
        s3.upload_file(full_path, "my_bucket", file_name)
        # call celery here...
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

My celery task:

```
def example_download_funciont(self):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    bucket = s3.Bucket("my_bucket")
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as data:
        file = bucket.download_fileobj(object_name, data)
    workbook = load_workbook(file)
    # [...]
```

Running this code I can upload it to s3. However, when I try to access it directly through the aws console I get this error:

```
AccessDeniedAccess DeniedAEEF2C5140AF4B82zNYFYcwehn+ZDxm+FuEI8mqrcCCU6BQzDdjd6mzOseMDanA6cPmu2VnbX3KvR978xN9v0QwOa7g=try { Object.defineProperty(screen, "availTop", { value: 0 }); } catch (e) {} try { Object.defineProperty(screen, "availLeft", { value: 0 }); } catch (e) {} try { Object.defineProperty(screen, "availWidth", { value: 2560 }); } catch (e) {} try { Object.defineProperty(screen, "availHeight", { value: 1080 }); } catch (e) {} try { Object.defineProperty(screen, "colorDepth", { value: 24 }); } catch (e) {} try { Object.defineProperty(screen, "pixelDepth", { value: 24 }); } catch (e) {} try { Object.defineProperty(navigator, "hardwareConcurrency", { value: 8 }); } catch (e) {} try { Object.defineProperty(navigator, "appVersion", { value: "5.0 (X11)" }); } catch (e) {} try { Object.defineProperty(navigator, "doNotTrack", { value: "unspecified" }); } catch (e) {} try { window.screenY = 0 } catch (e) { } try { window.screenTop = 0 } catch (e) { } try { window.top.window.outerHeight = 1051 } catch (e) { } try { window.screenX = 395 } catch (e) { } try { window.screenLeft = 395 } catch (e) { } try { window.top.window.outerWidth = 1856 } catch (e) { }
```

In the celery task I can't download the file. When I call `file` I get `None`.

Can someone point me to a guide? I saw it in the botocore documentation, but I didn't make it.